# How to convert a string into date-format in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a string like `23 July 1914` and want to convert it to `23/07/1914` date format.
But my code gives `error`.

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('1 June 2005','%d %m %Y')
print datetime_object
```

Comment: Python's errors are explicit (although Python 3 was a great improvement on that point). Take some time to carefully read the error: it should clearly points out what's wrong. At least, you should share that error with us.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error is in the format you are using to strip your string. You use `%m` as the format specifier for month, but this expects a 0 padded integer representing the month of the year (e.g. `06` for your example). What you want to use is `%B`, which expects an month of the year written out fully (e.g. `June` in your example).

For a full explanation of the `datetime` format specifiers please consult [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), and if you have any other issues please check there first.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you should be doing:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('1 June 2005','%d %B %Y')
s = datetime_object.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
print(s)
```

Output:

```
>>> 01/06/05
```

You see your `strptime` requires two parameters.

```
strptime(string[, format])
```

And the string will be converted to a `datetime` object according to a format you specify.

There are various formats

> %a - abbreviated weekday name
>   %A - full weekday name
>   %b - abbreviated month name
>   %B - full month name
>   %c - preferred date and time representation
>   %C - century number (the year divided by 100, range 00 to 99)
>   %d - day of the month (01 to 31)
>   %D - same as %m/%d/%y
>   %e - day of the month (1 to 31)
>   %g - like %G, but without the century
>   %G - 4-digit year corresponding to the ISO week number (see %V).
>   %h - same as %b
>   %H - hour, using a 24-hour clock (00 to 23)

The above are some examples. Take a look here for [formats](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Take a goood look at these two!

> %b - abbreviated month name
>   %B - full month name

It should be in a similar pattern to the string you provide. Confusing take a look at these examples.

```
>>> datetime.strptime('1 jul 2009','%d %b %Y')
datetime.datetime(2009, 7, 1, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.strptime('1 Jul 2009','%d %b %Y')
datetime.datetime(2009, 7, 1, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.strptime('jul 21 1996','%b %d %Y')
datetime.datetime(1996, 7, 21, 0, 0)
```

As you can see based on the format the string is turned into a datetime object. Now take a look!

```
>>> datetime.strptime('1 July 2009','%d %b %Y')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    datetime.strptime('1 July 2009','%d %b %Y')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 510, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 343, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '1 July 2009' does not match format '%d %b %Y'
```

Why error because `jun` or `Jun` (short form) stands for `%b`. When you supply a `June` it gets confused. Now what to do? Changed the format.

```
>>> datetime.strptime('1 July 2009','%d %B %Y')
datetime.datetime(2009, 7, 1, 0, 0)
```

Simple now converting the datetime object is simple enough.

```
>>> s = datetime.strptime('1 July 2009','%d %B %Y')
>>> s.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
'01/07/2009
```

Again the `%m` is the format for displaying it in months (numbers) read more about them.

Answer (score 0):

The [placeholder](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for "Month as locale’s full name." would be `%B` not `%m`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime_object = datetime.strptime('1 June 2005','%d %B %Y')
>>> print(datetime_object)
2005-06-01 00:00:00

>>> print(datetime_object.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
01/06/2005
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.strptime('1 June 2005', '%d %B %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
print(datetime.strptime('23 July 1914', '%d %B %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

For more info you can read about [strftime-strptime-behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

`%d` means "Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number."

`%m` means "Month as a zero-padded decimal number."

Neither day or month are supplied what you tell it to expect. What you need it `%B` for month (only if your locale is en_US), and `%-d` for day.